Sanitize a hostname using Boost C++
I'm trying to pass a hostname/ipv4/ipv6 to the ping utility in linux (to avoid using raw sockets, root), however, I want to ensure it's valid before running the command. For example, if a malicious domain was supplied, say
char host[] = "google.com;cat > pwned.txt";

the sanitizer should reject it because it would allow remote code execution
ping -c 4 google.com;cat > pwned.txt

So far, I've coded this below to detect a valid ipv4, ipv6 and hostname.
Question
The code smells imo, so I'd like to know if there's a better Boost C++ approach to sanitizing the user input?
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //char host[] = "google.com";
    char host[] = "google.com;cat > pwned.txt";

    std::string allowed = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-.";

    bool bValid = false;
    boost::asio::ip::address ipv4Addr;
    boost::asio::ip::address ipv6Addr;

    try
    {
        ipv4Addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host);
        bValid = ipv4Addr.is_v4();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "NOT ipv4: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        bValid = false;
    }

    if (!bValid)
    {
        // not ipv4, let's try ipv6
        try
        {
            ipv6Addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host);
            bValid = ipv6Addr.is_v6();
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "NOT ipv6: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            bValid = false;
        }

        if (!bValid)
        {   
            // ipv4 and ipv6 failed, try a string
            std::string hostname = std::string(host);
            if (hostname.find_first_not_of(allowed) != std::string::npos) {
                std::cerr << "NOT valid host" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    std::string sCommand = "ping -c 4 ";
    sCommand.append(host);
    std::cout << "Running PING command: " << sCommand << std::endl;
    int result = std::system(sCommand.c_str());
    if (result != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Command failed: " << result << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


If you didn't pass this string to the shell, there wouldn't be any danger of shell injection. Directly give the string to ping (using exec() instead of system()), separated by a single -- argument to do that.

Simply do not use std::system use boost process.

https://godbolt.org/z/3rGP6WqPq

FYI, std::string::find_first_not_of.

@MarekR, the code lacks a -- parameter. This is supposed to keep ping from interpreting it as commandline flag/option like e.g. --help. Otherwise it's pretty elegant, thumbs up!

@n. m. could be an AI - I've added your suggested change std::string::find_first_not_of. Much cleaner now. Thanks!

Why are you even trying to run a ping command?  Before you connect?  Why bother?  ping xyz.com tells you nothing about whether or not connecting to http://example.com/some/end/point is secure or not, nor whether or not the connection attempt will work.  In general, doing X to see if Y will work is utterly useless.  X is not Y so just because X fails doesn't mean Y will fail, and even if X works you still have to handle all possible responses for your actual work Y.

Like others said, don't sanitize, just don't unsafely pass arguments. Your ping tool will already sanitize, and you never invoked a shell.
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bp = boost::process;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::error_code ec;
        int code = bp::system(bp::search_path("ping"), "-c", "4", "--", argv[1], ec);
        std::cout << code << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
    }
}

Printing e.g.
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_filesystem && ./a.out 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=1.83 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=1.55 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=1.59 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=1.51 ms
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.516/1.626/1.834/0.126 ms
0 (Success)

In case you really need to parse the address anyways:

Parsing ipv4 address with Boost Spirit X3
URL parsing using boost::spirit
What is the nicest way to parse this in C++?


Added some hints on (elegantly?) parsing IP addresses

Rethinking...perhaps we could use the Boost C++ resolver to detect a valid  ipv4/ipv6/hostname. For example,
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
    std::string host = "google.com"; 

    try {
        auto results = resolver.resolve(host, "");
        for (auto &entry : results) {
            std::cout << "Good: " << entry.endpoint().address() << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Bad: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

Examples
std::string host = "google.com;cat > pwned.txt";


Bad: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)

std::string host = "google.com"; 


Good: 192.178.50.78

